# Leer archivo .xlsx con PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Estoy intentado leer las celdas de my archivo xlsx con [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) pero no lo consigo.

```
require_once('Classes/PHPExcel.php');
require_once('Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php');

$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('C:\xampp\htdocs\hotelplayagolfsitges\wp-content\tesipro.xlsx');

echo 'La celda A2 es: ' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A2')->getFormattedValue();
echo '<br/>La celda B1 es: ' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B2')->getCalculatedValue(); 
echo '<br/>La celda B1 es: ' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C2')->getCalculatedValue();
```

Tengo este código, el problema es que no sé si usar `getCalculatedValue()`, `getValue()`, `getFormattedValue()` o qué método utilizar ya que los he utilizado todos, pero el `Calculated` o el `Value` me devuelve toda la fórmula, y yo no quiero la fórmula, yo solo quiero obtener el resultado que hay en cada celda tal y como se ve en Excel.

Comment: Hola, 
nadie me puede ayudar?
Gracias!

Comment: Quizá la clase PHP que usas no es muy conocida :(

Comment: `getCalculatedValue()` funciona para mostrar el valor. ¿Podrías **[edit]** la pregunta agregando los valores de A2, B2 y C2, y los valores que imprime el script? Alternativamente, se puede ejecutar en [debug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16708771/5290909)

Comment: intenta con `getOldCalculatedValue ()`

Comment: necesitas si o si en el formato xlsx. No podrías convertir a csv?

Comment: Probaste con getValue() ? Yo también he estado jugando con esas funciones y getValue me ha resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar cambiar la ruta de tu .xlsx, ponerlo en la misma ruta donde tienes tus librerías "Classes". Creo que no está logrando encontrar el archivo. Lo utilicé en mi localhost y funcionó sin problemas:

```
<?php
require_once('excel/PHPExcel.php');
require_once('excel/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php');

$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('excel\archivo.xlsx');

echo 'La celda A1 es: ' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getFormattedValue();
echo '<br/>La celda B1 es: ' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B1')->getCalculatedValue(); 
echo '<br/>La celda B1 es: ' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C1')->getCalculatedValue();
?>
```